# Overriding a method returning a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, overriding

in my Silverlight 4 application I started creating and using some generics and now I stumbled upon the following problem:

In a non-generic class, I have a abstract method, that returns a generic class:

```
public abstract class DTO_Base()
{
  public abstract ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeBase> CreateBusinessObject();
}
```

The generic class is defined in the following way:

```
public abstract class ServiceModelBase<RootNodeType> where RootNodeType : ServiceNodeBase
```

Naturally, from DTO_Base derived classes will have to override the CreateBusinessObject method:

```
public class DTO_Editor : DTO_Base
{
  public override ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeBase> CreateBusinessObject()
  {
    // the object to return have to be of type ServiceModelEditor
    // which is derived from ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeEditor>
    // public class ServiceModelEditor : ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeEditor>

    // ServiceNodeEditor is derived from ServiceNodeBase
    // public class ServiceNodeEditor : ServiceNodeBase
    ServiceModelEditor target = new ServiceModelEditor()

    ...
    Functions to populate the 'target'
    ...

    return target;
  }
}
```

The line **return target;** causes an error, stating that it isn't possible to implicitly convert the type `ServiceModelEditor` in `ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeBase>`. Also, an explicit conversion via target as `ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeBase>` doesn't work.

How would I have to implement this method to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface IDTO<Node> where Node : ServiceNodeBase
{
    ServiceModelBase<Node> CreateBusinessObject();
}
public abstract class DTO_Base<Model,Node> : IDTO<Node>
    where Model : ServiceModelBase<Node>
    where Node : ServiceNodeBase
{
    public abstract Model CreateBusinessObject();


    #region IDTO<Node> Members

    ServiceModelBase<Node> IDTO<Node>.CreateBusinessObject()
    {
        return CreateBusinessObject();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class DTO_Editor : DTO_Base<ServiceModelEditor, ServiceNodeEditor>
{

    public override ServiceModelEditor CreateBusinessObject()
    {
        // the object to return have to be of type ServiceModelEditor
        // which is derived from ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeEditor>
        // public class ServiceModelEditor : ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeEditor>

        // ServiceNodeEditor is derived from ServiceNodeBase
        // public class ServiceNodeEditor : ServiceNodeBase
        ServiceModelEditor target = new ServiceModelEditor();


        return target;

    }
}
```

I have faced a similar problem before and the only thing reasonable to do is to make the core base class generic also. You can remove the `Model` generic parameter (and the interface) and it will look a little less scary, but you loose visibility on the functionality of `ServiceModelEditor` outside of the method.

Comment: Many thanks, this works! Even without the interface, so, is the interface you created necessary to preserve me from later trouble?

Answer (score 1):

As it is, you've *got* to return a `ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeBase>`. One option is to make your base class generic:

```
public abstract class DtoBase<T> where T : RootNodeType
{
    public abstract ServiceModelBase<T> CreateBusinessObject();
}
```

Then:

```
public class DtoEditor : DtoBase<ServiceNodeBase>
{
    public override ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeBase> CreateBusinessObject()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: "public class DtoEditor : DtoBase<ServiceNodeEditor>" I think

Comment: @KooKiz: I don't think so - not in terms of the return value from the method. `ServiceModelEditor` would have to derive from `ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeBase>` though.

Comment: Yeah but it's already mentionned in the code comments that ServiceModelEditor derives from ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeEditor>

Comment: @KooKiz: Then the question is internally inconsistent, basically :)

Comment: Then how to construct this consistently? The whole point in deriving ServiceModelEditor from ServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeEditor> is to have the generic type from the ServiceModelBase class to ServiceNodeEditor. If I would set it to ServiceNodeBase, I would not need this whole generics approach at all. This generic stuff seems to make the whole construction more complicated and more confusing, or I might just use generics in a wrong way.

Comment: @Aaginor: It's entirely possible you're overusing or abusing generics. It's also *possible* that covariance in .NET 4 would help you, but to be honest we don't know enough about what you're trying to achieve to give good advice.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is not easy to present enough information to describe the problem, without presenting to much and irrelevant informations. Anyway, I will have a closer look at covariance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net 4.0 I suggest you use interfaces to define your `ServiceModelBase` and specify an `out` variance modifier on that interface generic type:

```
class ServiceNodeBase { }
class ServiceNodeEditor : ServiceNodeBase {/*implementation*/}
//
interface IServiceModelBase<out RootNodeType>
    where RootNodeType : ServiceNodeBase { 
}
class ServiceModelEditor : IServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeEditor> {
    /*implementation*/
}
//
abstract class DTO_Base {
    public abstract IServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeBase> CreateBusinessObject();
}
class DTO_Editor : DTO_Base {
    public override IServiceModelBase<ServiceNodeBase> CreateBusinessObject() {
        return new ServiceModelEditor();
    }
}
```